# Errors routing with flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I'm making my first flask app using proper routing. I have drawn the route map below. The bold names represent files (on a side note if anyone knows how to draw nice route paths on here please do say!)

config.py
start.sh
start.sh
wgis.py
**Application**
 ....static
 ....__init_ _.py (ignore the space)
 ....templates
 ....functions.py
 ....routes.py
 ....second.py
 ....**plotlydash**
.........dashapp.py
**myenv**
 ....bin
  ....lib

I am having a couple of issues. These are:

1. I am unable to start the program without the command python -m flask run as opposed to just flask run alone.
2. I cannot get the dash app to be added to the application. The error code from **init**.py returns 'No module named plotlydash.dashboard'. It seems unable to look into the directory plotlydash and find dashapp. I have had similar issues trying to import python files from different files.

If anyone has any advice on either of these issues it would be great! I will post the minimal amount of code below which I think is needed (for brevity), but if miss anything out please let me know and ill get you it.

Cheers!

Start.sh

```
export FLASK_APP = wsgi.py
flask run
```

wgsi.py

```
from application import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, request



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_pyfile('/Users/ianholdroyd/Documents/Code/Graphs/Activity/web/practive/config.py')

with app.app_context():
    from . import routes

    from .plotlydash.dashapp import create_dashboard
    app = create_dashboard(app)

    # Compile static assets

    return app
```

Requirements.txt

```
    Brotli==1.0.7
click==7.1.2
dash==1.12.0
dash-core-components==1.10.0
dash-html-components==1.0.3
dash-renderer==1.4.1
dash-table==4.7.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Assets==2.0
Flask-Compress==1.5.0
future==0.18.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy
pandas
pathlib==1.0.1
plotly==4.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.13.0
pytz==2020.1
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
webassets==2.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
flask_kvsession
datetime
geopy
gpxpy
```

Comment: Can you show your requirements.txt?

Comment: Haven't used one. Is that an issue? All the modules I have used are on my laptop.

Comment: Yes it is. The unique way to replicate your current environment is by having all dependencies in a `requirements.txt`. So in a new environment you have the same set of   packages installed.

Comment: Try putting a `__init__.py` file inside plotlydash folder.

Comment: @Danizavtz Thanks for the reply. I've made the file and added it in. Do I have to remove all the import module functions at the top of each python file? If so how do I give them shorter names e.g. import numpy as np?

Comment: @RajSrujanJalem Imagining that the file format would have to be different for the different __init__.py function? How would it have to be changed so that the initial __init__ file was the one that was initially called to make the main app not the dash app instead.